# How to Create a custom tab layout that mimics the default tab text

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I need to create a custom tab layout, but I want the text to mimic the style used in the normal `TabLayout.TabView`.

To do that, I've set my text appearance to `TextAppearance.Design.Tab`.

If you take a look at `TabLayout` itself, you can see that's what `TabView`'s text uses:

```
mTabTextAppearance = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.TabLayout_tabTextAppearance, R.style.TextAppearance_Design_Tab);
```

...

`TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(mTextView, mTabTextAppearance);`

However, when my tabs display, I can clearly see the text is not the same.  It's very similar, but the default tab looks to be more bold.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to set the text appearance programmatically.  Setting `android:textAppearance` on the `TextView` in the XML file doesn't seem to do anything.  Setting the text appearance programmatically (like `TabLayout.TabView`) works.